# Owl carousel for images with different sizes?

Tags: jquery, css, image, owl-carousel

[I have seen this demo for images](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html)

I have the requirement that the owl carousel must be always same width and height. E.g. must fit into given boundaries.

The pictures should use `background-size: contain` to make them fit. So I fear I cannot use `img` tag directly.

The next picture must be right next to the next, no white space in between.

e.g. should look like this:

[image]

so the amount of pictures shown is unknown, as depending on the ratio and width of the picture

is there a way to do this with owl carousel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although this is an old question I had the same question. Here is my solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".owl-carousel").each(function(index, el) {
    var containerHeight = $(el).height();
    $(el).find("img").each(function(index, img) {
      var w = $(img).prop('naturalWidth');
      var h = $(img).prop('naturalHeight');
      $(img).css({
        'width': Math.round(containerHeight * w / h) + 'px',
        'height': containerHeight + 'px'
      });
    }),
    $(el).owlCarousel({
      autoWidth: true
    });
  });
});
```

It resizes images in carousel to fit desired height set for carousel container (honoring aspect ratio).

Full example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yzLqv3qk/

Comment: nice solution, i used a more complex server side solution for it (where width and ratio came from server, which is a lot uglier than this.

Comment: This actually works like a charm, but I have to refresh twice in order for the sizing to be set. What would I have to do to make it so that it resizes the images and displays them on 1st render?

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into a similar issue with Owl Carousel. Working with three different image aspect ratios within a single carousel, you could apply the same logic here.

First I made the outer `owl-container` a fluid width of the viewport:

```
#owl-container {
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}
```

Then made the `owl-item img` fit this:

```
#owl-carousel .item img {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0
}
```

Before giving each individual image aspect ratio a unique fluid width,
fitting within the above and enabling you to match each height (with a bit of back and forth calculating the correct percentages):

```
.landscape {
   width:100%;
}

.portrait {
  width:25%;
}

.square {
  width:50%
}
```

Leaving each slide's code looking something like this:

```
<div class="item landscape"><img src="../xyz.jpg" alt="xyz"></div>
<div class="item portrait"><img src="../xyz.jpg" alt="xyz"></div>
<div class="item square"><img src="../xyz.jpg" alt="xyz"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the container to whatever size you need it to be and set the images as backgrounds in css with the following for each image:

```
.item.item1{
   background: url(images/slide1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;

}

.item.item2{
   background: url(images/slide2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;

}
```

This will keep the images all the same size, but it will crop them as needed to fit the size you predefine. The downside with this method is that you have to define the images in your CSS, not the HTML - but I have used this method on OWL slider before.

Comment: well but background-size contain is must

Answer (score 0):

Yes a very old question, but I had to add some more to Arnie Schraufenziger answer, as his code send pictures on top.

```
$(".owl-carousel").each(function(index, el) {
    var containerHeight = $(el).height();
    $(el).find("img").each(function(index, img) {
        var w = $(img).prop('naturalWidth');
        var h = $(img).prop('naturalHeight');
        var winWidth = $(window).width();
        var differenceInHeight = containerHeight - (h / 2);
        if(w>h && winWidth >= 992){         
        $(img).css({
            'width': w + 'px',
            'height': 'auto',
            'max-height': containerHeight + 'px'
        });
        }else if (w>h && winWidth <= 991){
            $(img).css({
                'width': w + 'px',
                'height': 'auto',
                'max-height': containerHeight + 'px',
                'margin-top': differenceInHeight + 'px'
            });
        }else if(h>w && winWidth >= 992){
            $(img).css({
                'width': Math.round(containerHeight * w / h) + 'px',
                'height': containerHeight + 'px'
            });
        }else if(h>w && winWidth <= 991){
            $(img).css({
                'width': Math.round(containerHeight * w / h) + 'px',
                'height': containerHeight + 'px'
            });
        }
    }),
    $(el).owlCarousel({
      autoWidth: true
    });
  });
```

You can set the desired windows width to your liking ;)